# I need to spam the "C" Button until the Game Restarts

Tags: python, events, pygame

Hello i need to programm a Game with pygame for school. I nearly finish the Game but when i want to Press the "C" button in the Gameover loop then nothing happends and the game will not restart.
unti i spam the "C" Button. I dont think that there is a problem with the detection of pressing the button because i made a print command thatalways prints something when i press the "C" Button and it always print something out.
I hope you can help me with the Problem :)

```
from turtle import pos
import pygame
import time
from pygame.locals import *
import random
pygame.init()

dis_width = 600
dis_height = 400
pos_x = 303
pos_y = 370
x_change = 0
y_change = 0
enemie_pos_x = random.randint(180, 420)
enemie_pos_y = 30

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((dis_width, dis_height))
font_style = pygame.font.SysFont("bahnschrift", 25)
time_font = pygame.font.SysFont("bahnschrift", 25)

running=True
obj = False
obj2 = False
enemie = False
game_over = False
crash = True


start = time.time() + 0.1
tolleranz = 40
speed = 5
timer = 5
score = 0
displayscore = 0
highscore = 0
ROT = (255, 0, 0)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

pygame.display.update()

def stopwatch(time):
    value = time_font.render("Time: " + str(time), True, ROT)
    screen.blit(value, [0, 0])
    value2 = time_font.render("Score: " + str(score), True, ROT)
    screen.blit(value2, [0, 30])
    value6 = time_font.render("HighScore: " + str(highscore), True, ROT)
    screen.blit(value6, [0, 60])


def enemies():
    counter = 1
    global enemie_pos_x, enemie_pos_y, speed, aTimeRound, timer, displayscore, highscore
    enemie_pos_y += speed
    if aTimeRound > timer:


        speed += 5
        timer += 5
    if enemie_pos_y > 430:
        enemie_pos_y = 0
        enemie_pos_x = random.randint(180, 420)
        global score
        score += 1
        if highscore <= score:
            if highscore != score:
                
                highscore += 1
        displayscore = score


def gameoverF():
    global score, start, speed, timer, game_over, displayscore, highscore
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    value3 = time_font.render("GAMEOVER", True, ROT)
    screen.blit(value3, [230, 100])
    value6 = time_font.render("Score:" + str(displayscore), True, ROT)
    screen.blit(value6,[230, 150])
    value4 = time_font.render("Highscore: " + str(highscore), True, ROT)
    screen.blit(value4,[225, 200])
    value5 = time_font.render("Press 'C' to play again OR Press 'Q' to Quit", True, ROT)
    screen.blit(value5,[70,250])
    score = 0
    start = time.time()
    speed = 5
    timer = 5
    pygame.display.update()


                
    




while running:
    while game_over == True:
        
        for event in pygame.event.get():        # Bei jeden GameLoop die Liste an Events abfragen
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:    # Prüfen, ob der Eventtyp ein Tastendruck ist
                if event.key == ord("c"):  # Prüfen, ob die Cursor-Links-Taste gedrückt wurde...
                    game_over = False
                    speed = 5
                    timer = 5
                    score = 0
                    

                    
                    print("GEDRÜCKT!!!!!!!")
                if event.key == ord("q"):
                    pygame.quit()
                    
        gameoverF()
        
        
    #Messung der Zeit
    aTime = time.time()-start
    aTimeRound = round(time.time()-start,1)
    #print(aTime)

    #Malen der Steuer Kugel und der Linien    
    pos_x += x_change
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, ROT, (150,0),(150,400), 10)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, ROT, (450,0),(450,400), 10)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, [255,255,255],(pos_x,pos_y), 25)

    stopwatch(aTimeRound)
    enemies()

    pygame.draw.circle(screen, [255,255,255],(enemie_pos_x,enemie_pos_y), 25)

    #print( enemie_pos_x - pos_x)
    check_x = pos_x - enemie_pos_x
    if check_x < 0:
        check_x = check_x * -1
    print(check_x)

    if check_x < tolleranz and pos_y - enemie_pos_y < tolleranz:
            
        game_over = True





 
  














    clock.tick(30)
    if pos_x  <= 192:
        pos_x = 192
    if pos_x  >= 410:
        pos_x = 410
    for event in pygame.event.get():        # Bei jeden GameLoop die Liste an Events abfragen
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:    # Prüfen, ob der Eventtyp ein Tastendruck ist
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == ord("a"):  # Prüfen, ob die Cursor-Links-Taste gedrückt wurde...
                x_change = -10   
                y_change = 0                # Aktion bei Cursor-Links
                
      
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == ord("d"):
                x_change = 10
                y_change = 0
               

                
    

    pygame.display.update()

gameoverF()
```

Answer (score 3):

Played your game got highscore of 22 oh I mean I read the code and and I debugged it

Well actually playing was the debugging haha. The problem is that after you press C game restarts as it should but the enemy which hit you is not removed and it instantly kills you again and moves tiny bit lower. By spamming C you move it out of screen and game continues

Simple fix to reset enemy pose when C is pressed

```
if event.key == ord("c"):
    enemie_pos_y = 30 # Reset enemy pose
```

Keep up the good work!

Comment: `if event.key == pygame.K_c`  might be more intuitive.